# Resolving Sinatra and HTTParty method name clashes

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mixins, httparty

In my Sinatra app, I am using a class with HTTParty as mixin.

```
class A
  include HTTParty
  format :json

  def fetch arguments
    get(:query => arguments)
  end
end
```

When I try to call the fetch (when the class instance is created inside a `get` block), I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block
```

When I run the `get` method as `HTTParty.get` all works fine. How I can resolve these name clashes or the problem is with something else? I'd really like to use HTTParty as a mixin, so I can set all the options once.

Thanks in advance!

I am using sinatra 1.3.2 and httparty 0.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get method is a class method.
Please try to the following, but I've not tried it out yet...

```
self.class.get
```